# Image upload to FB not visible for frineds on my timeline/

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

from my app Image is uploaded to FB and shows up on the timeline but its only available on my page. Even when I share or like it. It's not shared to any of my friends.

This is how I do it.
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"SnapShot!!!", @"message",
                                    image, @"source",
                                    nil];

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                          NSLog(@"Post Result : %@ error : %@", result, error);
                          if (error != null) {
                              NSLog(@"Posted");
                          }

                      }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL. I didn't change the app settings from Sandboxing enabled to disabled, so it was only available for development team.